# Magento 2 "No such entity" debug when creating customer

Tags: magento2, data-migration-tool

I am creating an account which is recently developed in Magento 2.2.4 and migrated from Magento 1.9.1.0.

I am getting error "No such entity with email = rr@g.com, websiteId = 1"

I am not finding the way that how to know which empty is missing in my database.While I have already checked each tables manually which is responsible to create an account.

I wanna know is there any tool that help to know exactly what is missing in my DB.

My website is multi website.

While Debugging code in file

vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php

```
try {

            // If customer exists existing hash will be used by Repository
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->save($customer, $hash);
        } catch (AlreadyExistsException $e) {
            throw new InputMismatchException(
                __('A customer with the same email already exists in an associated website.')
            );
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
```

How to debug code after line

```
$customer = $this->customerRepository->save($customer, $hash);
```

while creating account every time its going to

```
} catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                throw $e;
            }
```

and produce error

> "No such entity with email = rr@g.com, websiteId = 1"

Is there any way we can through error what exactly is missing in my DB?

Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution akgola

Comment: @venkataprasad,yes I found the solution.Please check solution  https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/565

Comment: I am facing the same problem in magento2 https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/278866/75909 please have a look if you found any solution

Comment: @Ghulam.M ,did you check thread  github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/565  ?

Comment: what actually you did to resolve the issue increased "max_input_vars" or eav_attribute changes?